# Kinetic term of the Majorana Lagrangian

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, majorana-fermions

I want to expand the kinetic term of the Majorana Lagrangian (considering only a left handed Weyl spinor) from

$$\mathcal{L}= \frac{1}{2} \bar{\psi}_M i \gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu} \psi$$

So I wrote :$$\bar{\psi}_M \equiv \psi^{\dagger}_M \gamma^0 =  \begin{pmatrix}
\psi^{\dagger}_L & -i\psi^{T}_L \sigma^2
\end{pmatrix}     \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
-i \psi^{T}_L \sigma^2 & \psi^{\dagger}_L
\end{pmatrix}$$

And the representation with the representation of the Dirac matrices:
$$\gamma^0 = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu}  \\
\bar{\sigma^{\mu}} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

So the expression for the lagrangian becomes:
$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{i}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
-i \psi^{T}_L \sigma^2 & \psi^{\dagger}_L
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sigma^{\mu}  \\
\bar{\sigma^{\mu}} & 0 
\end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{\mu}\psi_L  \\
\partial_{\mu} i \sigma^2 \psi^{*}_L 
\end{pmatrix} $$

And just by multiplying these matrices we finally obtain:
$$\mathcal{L}= \frac{i}{2} \left[ \psi^{\dagger}_L \bar{\sigma^{\mu}} \partial_{\mu} \psi_L + \psi^T_L \sigma^2 \sigma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu} \sigma_2 \psi^{*}_L \right]$$

But I know that this term should be equal to

$$\mathcal{L}=i\psi^{\dagger}_L \bar{\sigma^{\mu}} \partial_{\mu} \psi_L$$

Which leads me to think that somehow the second term in the previous equation is equal to the first one, but I have not been able to derive that.Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

For the Pauli matrices 
$$
\sigma_2 \sigma_i \sigma_2 = -\sigma_i^*
$$
where the $*$ denotes the matrix with complex-conjuated entries.

Comment: Also important to note that the spinors must anticommute, otherwise you will get zero